# Loop through list of int and replace a value in a string with that int

Tags: python

I have a list of accounts:

```
account = [79173,84830,86279]
```

I have a string which contains n information, including an account id between `<key_value>` and `</key_value>`:

```
import re

text_msg = """
      <field>
        <field_name>accountinfoid2</field_name>
        <key_value>286249</key_value>
        <target_name>Field2</target_name>
        <target_type>Integer</target_type>
        <target_format />
        <target_length>-1</target_length>
        <target_precision>-1</target_precision>
        <target_decimal_symbol />
        <target_grouping_symbol />
        <target_currency_symbol />
        <target_null_string />
        <target_aggregation_type>-</target_aggregation_type>
      </field>
"""
```

What I need is to replace `286249` with account id from the list `account`:

```xml
<field>
        <field_name>accountinfoid2</field_name>
        <key_value>79173</key_value>
        <target_name>Field2</target_name>
        <target_type>Integer</target_type>
        <target_format />
        <target_length>-1</target_length>
        <target_precision>-1</target_precision>
        <target_decimal_symbol />
        <target_grouping_symbol />
        <target_currency_symbol />
        <target_null_string />
        <target_aggregation_type>-</target_aggregation_type>
      </field>
      <field>
        <field_name>accountinfoid2</field_name>
        <key_value>84830</key_value>
        <target_name>Field2</target_name>
        <target_type>Integer</target_type>
        <target_format />
        <target_length>-1</target_length>
        <target_precision>-1</target_precision>
        <target_decimal_symbol />
        <target_grouping_symbol />
        <target_currency_symbol />
        <target_null_string />
        <target_aggregation_type>-</target_aggregation_type>
      </field>
<field>
        <field_name>accountinfoid2</field_name>
        <key_value>86279</key_value>
        <target_name>Field2</target_name>
        <target_type>Integer</target_type>
        <target_format />
        <target_length>-1</target_length>
        <target_precision>-1</target_precision>
        <target_decimal_symbol />
        <target_grouping_symbol />
        <target_currency_symbol />
        <target_null_string />
        <target_aggregation_type>-</target_aggregation_type>
      </field>
```

I've tried:

```
completed_account = []
for i in account:
    temp = re.sub('(?<=<key_value>).*?(?=</key_value>)',i,text_msg,flags=re.DOTALL)
    completed_account.append(temp)
print(completed_account)
```

and got the error:

```
decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, int found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you should never treat regexp as a valid tool when manipulating a markup data (xml/html) - use a proper parsers

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, can you elaborate on it, please?

Comment: this is a well-known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags . Also find another links here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075 section "Do not use regex to parse HTML:"

Comment: OK, thank you for the links. For my purposes, it worked alright but I will keep the issues in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub` expects the second argument (replacement) to be a string or a function.

Try casting `i` to a string:

```py
completed_account = []
for i in account:
    temp = re.sub('(?<=<key_value>).*?(?=</key_value>)', str(i), text_msg, flags=re.DOTALL)
    completed_account.append(temp)
print(completed_account)
```

Comment: yeah, the solution was much easy. Thank you! I will accept your reply in 11 min as per Stack's requirements.

Comment: You're welcome! It's often easier when it's someone else's code ;)